# getting "The requested resource is in use" when using sharpDX

Tags: c#, resources, device, sharpdx

Here my code sample

```
  directInput = new DirectInput();// Initialize DirectInput
            deviceGuid = Guid.Empty;// Find a Joystick Guid

            foreach (DeviceInstance deviceInstance in directInput.GetDevices(DeviceType.Gamepad, DeviceEnumerationFlags.AllDevices))
            { deviceGuid = deviceInstance.InstanceGuid; }


            directInput = new DirectInput();
            device = new Joystick(directInput, deviceGuid);
            device.Acquire();
            device.Properties.BufferSize = 128;
            while (true)
            {
                device.Poll();
                var data = device.GetBufferedData();
                foreach (var state in data)
                {
                    if (state.Offset == JoystickOffset.X)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show( state.Value.ToString() );
                    }
                }
            }
```

This sample should get me a changed state but I get "The requested resource is in use" when setting the buffer size. I'm able to use the sharpDX code to get button states with no issues by using the deviceState.Buttons[]. Works great but no luck with the GetBufferedData.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and what worked for me was to

```
device.Acquire();
device.Properties.BufferSize = 128;
```

to

```
device.Properties.BufferSize = 128;
device.Acquire();
```